# how to compare values with previous values in groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
  ID     date          no      start      end
  1      01-01-2019    10      101.23     112.23
  2      02-01-2019    10      112.23     120.43
  3      03-01-2019    10      121.23     130.23
  4      04-01-2019    10      130.23     140.43
  5      01-01-2019    11      101        112 
  6      02-01-2019    11      112        120
  7      03-01-2019    11      130        140
  8      04-01-2019    11      140        150.43
```

I want to check current rows `end` with next rows `start` value grouping by `no`and if there is a difference then want to set a flag and the difference to be calculated

Following is my desired dataframe

```
  ID     date          no      start      end      flag   diff
  1      01-01-2019    10      101.23     112.23   0      0 
  2      02-01-2019    10      112.23     120.43   0      0
  3      03-01-2019    10      121.23     130.23   1      1
  4      04-01-2019    10      130.23     140.43   0      0
  5      01-01-2019    11      101        112      0      0
  6      02-01-2019    11      112        120      0      0
  7      03-01-2019    11      130        140      1      10
  8      04-01-2019    11      140        150.43   0      0
```

How can I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create Series by [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) and replace first `NaN`s by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html), compare by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and cast mask to integer, for another column get difference:

```
s = df.groupby('no')['end'].shift().fillna(df['start'])
df['flag'] = df['start'].ne(s).astype(int)
df['diff'] = df['start'] - s
print (df)
   ID        date  no   start     end  flag  diff
0   1  01-01-2019  10  101.23  112.23     0   0.0
1   2  02-01-2019  10  112.23  120.43     0   0.0
2   3  03-01-2019  10  121.23  130.23     1   0.8
3   4  04-01-2019  10  130.23  140.43     0   0.0
4   5  01-01-2019  11  101.00  112.00     0   0.0
5   6  02-01-2019  11  112.00  120.00     0   0.0
6   7  03-01-2019  11  130.00  140.00     1  10.0
7   8  04-01-2019  11  140.00  150.43     0   0.0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (s)
0    101.23
1    112.23
2    120.43
3    130.23
4    101.00
5    112.00
6    120.00
7    140.00
Name: end, dtype: float64
```

Comment: It may be helpful to explain shift and ne a little more for newer users. Shift shifts the values of a column down by one row here in order to set the end column values next to the start column values in a way that they match. ne means not equal, giving a True/False response; it's cast to int to match the 0/1 format of the "flag" column.